# C# MVC get all model validation errors with submodel errors included

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to get with filter all model validation errors. So example:

My HealthCenterViewModel

```
public class HealthCenterViewModel {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string FaxNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public AddressModel Address { get; set; }

        ...

}

public class AddressModel {
        [Required]
        public string Street { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string StreetNumber { get; set; }

        ... }
```

I want to get all model validations error with included submodel errors, so I am using this `ValidationActionFilter`

```
public class ValidationActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var modelState = actionContext.ModelState;

            if (!modelState.IsValid)
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                     .CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, modelState);
        }
    }
```

problem is that I get always back this:

```
model.Address:"The Address field is required."
model.Email:"The Email field is required."
model.PhoneNumber:"The PhoneNumber field is required."
model.ShortName:"The ShortName field is required."
```

but nothing about which property from `Address` model are required.

Is it possible somehow to get also back validation errors messages from Address?

I would like to get back something like:

```
model.Address.Street:"The Address.Street field is required."
model.Address.StreetNumber:"The AddressStreetNumber field is required."
```

Comment: Short answer is no - the `DefaultModelBinder` will add a validation error for `Address` is no values are posted and does not 'recursively' add a `ModelStateError` for properties of `AddressModel` (no real point since its `null`).

Comment: In MVC (within a controller method), you can use `AddressModel address = new AddressModel(); bool isValid = TryValidateModel(address, "Address");` to add the validation errors for `Address.Street` and `Address.StreetNumber` to `ModelState`, but not sure how to do that with WebAPI

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in your Startup class and reformat as you want by yourself:

```
 services.AddControllers().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
            {
                options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
                {
                    var errorStr = string.Join(" ", actionContext.ModelState
                        .SelectMany(v =>
                            !v.Key.Contains(".")
                                ? v.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)
                                : v.Value.Errors.Select(e =>
                                    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v.Key.Split(".").LastOrDefault())
                                        ? e.ErrorMessage.Replace(v.Key.Split(".").LastOrDefault(), v.Key)
                                        : e.ErrorMessage)));

                    throw new AppException(errorStr, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                };
            })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).